# FullCalendar event title shown on every day, not just first day

Tags: fullcalendar

Using Fullcalendar.io an event that spans over multiple days shows the title on just the FIRST day and also on the far left of the next row if the event spans across multiple rows.

I would like the title to appear on EVERY day.

Demo showing title across all days
[image]

Comment: There is currently no functionality for this. Consider making a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) (P.S. I'm not a fullcalendar team member so my opinion isn't necessarily relevant, but personally I don't really see why it would be necessary...it's pretty clear what the name of the event is, if you look across to the beginning of the event. This just looks like it would add clutter. As a workaround though to get a similar effect, you could create a daily recurring event instead of one long event.)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have a very specific requirement so the calendar can be used for property availability so each event 'title' will be a price, so each price needs to show in each cell.

Comment: Ok. Well my comment above already explains the options available to you. I don't follow the logic for why the title including a price means you are obliged to show it in each cell though, I must say. Do you mean it's a price for a nightly stay in the property? If so then, in my mind, a recurring event would make a much more logical way of showing the data in any case, and would also basically achieve your goal. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin for further info on ways you can set up recurring events.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into the recurring field.  Currently the events are being pulled from a database with date blocks (2023-01-01 to 2023-01-20) and this block represents a set price.  I just wanted this price to appear on each day.

Comment: So it's a price for the whole block, or a single night? If you repeat it on each day, to a user it will look like a nightly price

Comment: Price for a single night.  I could write some code to convert the start date and end date to create seperate events I guess instead of one long booking.

Comment: Yeah, or use those dates as the boundaries of a daily recurring event - that's probably simpler.